# Invalid date on one system; perfectly valid on another system?

Tags: date, time

My code takes a start hour, and then defines a few other date/time variables from that start hour. Like so:

```
shour=$(date -d "yesterday 3PM" -u)

dd=$(date "+%d" -d "$shour" -u) 

sdate=$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$shour" -u)
```

this returns;

```
date: invalid date 'Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020'
date: invalid date 'Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020'
```

pulling my hair out over this!

Comment: Which distro does it work on? Which distro does it fail on? Can you echo "${shour}" and the dd and the sdate immediately you have assignedm then? Can you run date --version on each distro? Please edit the question to include this helpful information.

Comment: Both on RHEL7. Tried with options first but returns the same error.

Comment: What is the locale on each system?

Comment: I can echo $shour no problem. It returns : "Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020". Doesn't allow me to assign dd or sdate just returns that error.

Comment: date --version returns "Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc. License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later" on BOTH systems

Comment: Trying to do date calculations with a locale-specific date format and human-readable data forms is arguably the computing equivalent of tying both hands behind one's back.

Comment: The output of date command respects locales what make it unreadable for the same command. Try to use `date -u -I ...`

Comment: Notably, you adjust the hour beck to 15:00, but don't use the hour in the two example outputs. I assume there are other uses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`date` can't read the default output `Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020`

Any `date` output you want to process again in `date` needs the output to be formatted with the format string `'+%F %T'`.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Still don't quite understand why it did work on my other machine.

Comment: Indeed.  ISO 8601 is the way to go if one is performing a round trip back into the `date` program, or even date→string→date round trips in general.  (Note that this does _not_ imply using UTC, so add `%z` for the more general case.)  https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/open-standards-for-government/date-times-and-time-stamps-standard#summary-of-the-standards-use-for-government https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/?p=94965

Answer (score 0):

I think the placement of the year could be the problem. While this fails:

```
host:~ # date -d 'Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020' 
date: invalid date ‘Thu 16 Jan 15:00:00 UTC 2020
```

this works in my VM:

```
host:~ # date -d 'Thu 16 Jan 2020 15:00:00 UTC' 
Thu Jan 16 16:00:00 CET 2020
```

I added a date format to the first statement, that seems to work:

```
shour=$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "yesterday 3PM" -u)
ddate="$(date -d "${shour}" -u)"
sdate=$(date "+%Y%m%d" -d "$shour" -u)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `date`'s `-R` option:

> ```
>    -R, --rfc-email
>           output date and time in RFC 5322 format.  Example: Mon, 14 Aug 2006 02:34:56 -0600
> ```

```
date -d "yesterday 3PM" -R
Thu, 16 Jan 2020 15:00:00 +0100
date -d "$(date -d "yesterday 3PM" -R)" +%s
1579183200
```